# Finding $\int_0^\infty\frac{a^x-b^x}{c^x-d^x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

So I was reading "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, Enlarged, corrected, and English version when I stumbled upon this very interesting identity: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{a^x-b^x}{c^x-d^x}dx=\frac1{\ln\frac cd}\left(\psi\left(\frac{\ln\frac cb}{\ln\frac cd}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\ln\frac ca}{\ln\frac cd}\right)\right)$$ found in section 3.311, where $\psi$ is the digamma function. The authors didn't provide limits on $a,b,c,$ and $d$ but I am guessing that either $c>a,b$ or $d>a,b$. This identity probably came from heaven or something, because I can't even attack this thing in any logical way. I don't know how to apply the Taylor series which would at least eliminate the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can begin by doing the following series of transformation.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a^x-b^x}{c^x-d^x} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{a}{c} \right)^{x} - \left( \frac{b}{c} \right)^{x}}{1-\left( \frac{d}{c} \right)^{x}} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\ln \left( \frac{c}{a} \right)x} - e^{-\ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)x}}{1-e^{-\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)x}} dx
$$
We can then do the following change of variables: $\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)x = t$. Which leads to the following integral.
$$
\frac{1}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{a} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t \right) - \exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t\right)}{1-e^{-t}} dt
$$
We can see the integral resembeling an integral repersentation of the digamma function that is as follows.
$$
\psi(z) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}} dt
$$
We will do some simple transformations to get us through the last leg.
$$
\frac{1}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} -\frac{e^{-t}}{t} +\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{a} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t \right) - \exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t\right)}{1-e^{-t}} + \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t \right)}{1-e^{-t}}dt - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{a} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}t \right)}{1-e^{-t}}dt \right)
$$
Directly employing the integral repersentation of the digamma function we find.
$$
\frac{1}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)} \left( \psi \left(\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{b} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}\right) - \psi \left(\frac{\ln \left( \frac{c}{a} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{c}{d} \right)}\right)\right)
$$

QED

Some have comented that this doesn't seem to work for all values. The only restriction I can see that may potentially arise is for all the constants to be positive.

Comment: But shouldn't $c$ and $d$ be bigger than $a$ and $b$ for the integrand to approach $0$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh Yes on its face, but the original integral diverges for the same values of the constants that the digamma expression does. The only reason I say they probably should be positive is because Im unsure to how branch cuts of the logithm and the digamma function would interact.